# Php Curl request Content Type header

Tags: php, curl

im trying to execute a curl request from my server. In local works perfectly, when i upload the script into the remote server it doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
$ch = curl_init( $url );
$payload = json_encode( array( "pIdPostazione"=>4 ) );
echo $payload;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```

On local server this is the header:

```
Array ( [url] => http:/xxxxxxx [content_type] => application/json; charset=utf-8 [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 270 [request_size] => 151 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.125 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0.062 [pretransfer_time] => 0.062 [size_upload] => 19 [size_download] => 634 [speed_download] => 5072 [speed_upload] => 152 [download_content_length] => 634 [upload_content_length] => 19 [starttransfer_time] => 0.125 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => xxxxx [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => xxx[local_ip] => xxxxx [local_port] => xxxx)
```

When the script is executed from the remote server the header content type and other header fields are empty:

```
Array ( [url] => xxxxx [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.000164 [namelookup_time] => 4.0E-5 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 0 [local_ip] => [local_port] => 0 )
```

Why????

These are the versions:
Local: Php 5.5.30, Curl 7.42.1
Remote: Php 5.6.21,Curl 7.38.0

Thanks!

This is the whole code that i use:

```
$ch = curl_init( $url );
# Setup request to send json via POST.
$payload = json_encode( array( "pIdPostazione"=>4 ) );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
# Send request.
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === false) $result = curl_error($ch);


$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($info);        
curl_close($ch);
```

Another question/info: why from local machine and from my another remote server i can see the request header as follow:

```
 [request_header] => POST /SFCTIO.asmx/GetNextVar HTTP/1.1 Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:65080 Content-Type: application/json Accept: application/json Content-Length: 19 )
```

and from the server where request return connection refused curl wont print the request header?

I'm confused

Comment: Please provide your whole code including the `curl_exec()` and even your `print_r()` used to create the output above.

Comment: Can you see if curl is raising some kind of error?, Try to use the function curl_errno in order to catch the curl reported errors.  Try to see php errors in /var/log/apache2/error.log or /var/log/httpd/error.log. If you are using Centos 6/7 try to deactivate SELinux policy "httpd_can_network_connect" (With: setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect). Check if the firewall allow to perform external requests against the destination URL.

Comment: The `Content-Type` header is sent by the server to the client. If the client sends it to the server it is ignored. What you're looking for is the [Accept](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) header: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));`

Comment: Mike, the header Accept insted of Content type doesn't work. @Juan-lago, curl return "connection refused" from server, but i think is because the content type of the request is blank, The server accept only json request.